# "The package linux-headers-5.11.0-37 needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it."

Tags: archive, linux-headers

I recently tried to install an upgrade but I keep getting the following error:

**The package linux-headers-5.11.0-37 needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it."**

How do I fix this?

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu did you upgrade to?  The reason I ask is because that kernel version is only available in 20.04 LTS and 21.04.  21.10 does not have it in the repos.